Start LDAP server at boot with Apache Directory Studio
I have an LDAP server running and configured with apache directory studio in linux, but the server stops running when the apache studio window closes and needs to be run manually each time. I want the ldap server to start running automatically on boot, but from what i tried, apache directory studio only has a graphic interface and no command lines or config i can use to do this.
Do i need to install apacheds separately from studio and manage to ldap server from there ? If yes, how ?
I'm very new to LDAP, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Are we talking about the ApacheDS embedded LDAP server?

yes i believe so, i created it with the apache directory studio GUI

I guess its desired behavior then, the server only runs in the context of the ApacheDS session. You should setup a dedicated one.
